# Pointer arithmetic in C not pointing to the correct variables if I don't print the address of the variables

Tags: c, gcc

So I'm doing pointer arithmetic homework and I need to decrement and increment pointers with this as its expected [outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRCaG.png). This is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    int d = 10;
    int c = 8;
    int b = 6;
    int a = 4;

    int *ptr; //these lines are given

    printf("decrement \n");
    for (ptr = &d; ptr >= &a; ptr--)
    {
        printf("%d \n",*ptr);
    }

    printf("increment \n");
    for (ptr = &a; ptr <= &d; ptr++)
    {
        printf("%d \n",*ptr);
    }
}
```

But the results skip 8 and 6:

```
decrement
10
4
increment
4
10
```

And so I decided to print the addresses at the beginning to help debug

```
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&d);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&c);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&a);
    printf("%p\n",(void*)&b);
```

But after running it, it just works

```
000000fc6a9ffb34
000000fc6a9ffb30
000000fc6a9ffb28
000000fc6a9ffb2c
decrement
10
8
6 
4
increment
4
6
8
10
```

So I know that the logic works out, but it just doesn't work without printing first and I don't know why

I'm using Vscode and GCC

Comment: When things' addresses aren't referenced, they might not have addresses. There's also no guarantee on how things are ordered within the function's stack frame, in general.

Comment: You can't treat local variables as an array, that's just not how things works. It *will* lead to *undefined behavior* and make your program *ill-formed*. Wherever you're learning this from you should throw it away.

Comment: On another note, please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text *as text*. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This is part of my college CS course, currently I'm asking if I'm allowed to turn the variables into an array. Also I'm quite sure that this would work if I was using TurboC which is what my school is recommending, though I did get a an OK to use vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I know that the logic works out, but it just doesn't work without printing first

*Undefined behavior* (UB), anything may happen.

---

```
int d = 10;
int a = 4;
int *ptr = &d; 
    ptr >= &a
```

`ptr >= &a` is *undefined behavior* (UB).

Order comparisons of pointers in C are UB when not part of the same array (or one after).

`ptr--` is also UB as that attmepts to form the address before `d`.  Pointer math only good within an array/object (or one after)

Comment: In OP's case, I suspect lack of `printf("%p\n",(void*)&c); printf("%p\n",(void*)&b);` simply optimzed away the `b, c` as they are not used.  Still `ptr >= &a` remains UB.

Answer (score 0):

your program have four different variables not an array of size four. So address of variables is unpredictable.

```
    int d = 10;
    int c = 8;
    int b = 6;
    int a = 4;
```

in Array memory is allocated contiguously, so use array if you want to do so.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int arr[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    // increment
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        printf("%d\n",*(arr + i));
    // decrement
    printf("-------------------------------\n");
    for(int i=3; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%d\n",*(arr + i));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you are not using variables b and c, just a and d - therefore (I suspect) the implementation is optimizing them away

In the second example, you are using variables all four variables a, b, c and d therefore they cannot be optimised away